# Conditional rendering of HTML segment using render_template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am calling `render_template` from a couple of different places, and I'd like to control whether I render certain HTML segments, depending on where I'm calling from.

For example:

```
render_template('index.html', form=form, show_results=1)
```

I intended to use the `show_results` bool to flag whether the optional segment should be rendered or not. However, I'm missing what wrapper I should have in the optional  delimited portion of the HTML code to control whether the segment should be rendered or not.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use an [if block](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#if):

```
{% if show_results %}
    show the results
{% endif %}
```